# Merge images Based on Cell Path

Tags: excel, vba

I Had a Ser of Constraint in making the Images to merge in the Ratio of Combination, generates possible combinations of m elements from the set of element with size n. A number of possible combinations, as shown in Combinatorics. Combinations, arrangements, and permutations are

```
C_{n}^m=\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!},
```

For this, I can Make the Each Combination in the Celle based image Path Value
For Examples

```
Column A- Image One Path
Column B - Image Two Path
Column C - In Which name Combined image to be Saved,
```

I want to select a set of 20 cells and run a macro that combines Images and save it.

I am just a kid, Please if any want to train and help me out, please suggest some ideas or Module

Comment: It is nice seeing kids learning and trying to code. Your question is a bit unclear, I would suggest to get and adult to help you edit it and make it more clear

Comment: While excel is easy to use for storing data, it's not so good for writing programs to manipulate external things such as images. You might find it easier to use a programming language like Python or Powershell for this kind of task.